# UICollectionView height is not correct

Tags: ios

I want to embed a UICollectionView inside a UIScrollView (I know it's not good practice but I have my reasons to do that).
I created a UICollectionView subclass that set intrinsicContentSize based on content size

```
class EmebedableCollectionView: UICollectionView {
    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        let size = self.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize
        let result = CGSize(width: max(size.width,1), height: max(size.height + 20,1))
        self.setNeedsLayout()
        return result
    }


    override var contentSize: CGSize {
        didSet {
            self.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
        }
    }
}
```

then in a container view, I create a height constraints for the collection view

```
@IBOutlet weak var productsHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

and update it based on UICollectionView intrinsicContentSize

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    for subview in productsContainerView.subviews.first!.subviews where subview is UICollectionView {
        productsHeightConstraint.constant = subview.intrinsicContentSize.height
        productsContainerView.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

The problem is: the container view height is not correct, but when I push a new view controller and get back, it update the height to be correct. so what's wrong in my code?

Comment: Explain the line `self.setNeedsLayout()` please. What do you think it does?

Comment: I was trying to let the UICollectionView re-layout when content size change

Comment: Maybe, but by the time that happens you have already obtained the value of `result` that you are about to return, so that line is pointless in that place, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, you are right. It changes nothing

Comment: It does worse than nothing. If it causes the size to change, it actually _causes_ this method to return the wrong answer.

Comment: Ops! this's worse! all I need to do is to embed a UICollectionView inside UIScrollView in some pages